# Given N students each student sends K messages to any other student

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are N students, each student sends K different messages to any other student, 260 messages sent, how many students in the class?

Im struggling to solve this one, tried to solve it using the summation of in degree and out-degree using the 260 but it didn't work.

Comment: Normally, “any other” means one other, but they can pick which one. Did you mean “every other”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if the number of students is $N$, then every student sends $(N-1)K$ messages in total, as they send $K$ messages to every other student.

Thus, in total, $N(N-1)K=260$ messages are sent. As $N$ is a positive integer, we need that $N$, $N-1$ and $N(N-1)$ all divide 260. But the divisors of 260 are "1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 13, 20, 26, 52, 65, 130, 260". Thus, the only possibilities are that $N=5$, $K=13$ or that $N=2$ and $K=130$.